# RangeIndex object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, indexing, slice

I am reading values from text file and and trying to find index of sub strings like below

```
df=pd.read_csv('break_sent.txt', index_col=False,encoding='utf-8',delimiter="\n",names=['sent'])
#print(df[:50])
#df.index = list(df.index)
df1= df[40:50]
print(len(df))
print(df1.index)
print("-------------------------------------------")
for i,row in df1.iterrows():
    string = row['sent']
    #print("string",string)
    d = df1[df1.sent.str.match(string)] # if the result includes more than 1 value then we know that substring and its matching parent string are present, then I will eliminate the substring from the dataframe
    if len(d.index > 2):
        index_val = df.index(string)
        df.drop(df.index(string),inpace=True)
        df.reset_index(level=None, drop=True, inplace=True)
```

when I run this code, I am getting the below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "process.py", line 15, in <module>
    index_val = df.index(string)
    TypeError: 'RangeIndex' object is not callable
```

I tried to convert the range index to List

```
df.index = list(df.index)
```

but then I got Int64Index is not callable. How can I get the index of the string ?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
df.drop(df.index(string),inpace=True)
```

to

```
df.drop(index=string, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `df.index` on the dataframe, rather than on your search string. So:

```py
matched_rows = df.index[df1.sent.str.match(string)]
```

will give you the rows that match your string. You should then be able to pass that output to `df.drop`:

```py
if len(matched_rows) > 2:
  df.drop(matched_rows, inplace=True)
  df.reset_index(level=None, drop=True, inplace=True)
```

I may not have grasped the exact details of what you're trying to do, but hopefully that points you in the right direction.